# Jacobi form to Weierstrass form . . . lattices included .... polynomial factoring in the way

Tags: complex-analysis, galois-theory, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals, galois-extensions

**Slightly more meat edit :**
I want to solve this integral

$$ J_{k=1} = \int dt \sqrt(2 t^6 - 2 t^5 - t^4 + t^2 + 1) - 1 $$
I know about some approximation schemes, but I want to grow bigger so I am venturing to learn what seasoned mathematicians would do.
The below polynomial is cute

$$2 t^6 - 2 t^5 - t^4 + t^2 + 1$$
So I have decided to think about it for a while. I feel like may be if I can factor this somehow things will be great because I can then be able to may be split rewrite the integral in some fashion.

So I have gone the route of thinking of checking what sort of roots are possible and so forth. I had some conversation and did deep self reflection about the possibility of looking at splitting fields, and Galois groups and so forth. A few non-trivial things came up.  I am considering this route because It will be cute to write a paper with some Hasse lattice. However the only lattice I have now is a baby version associated with complex roots.

I am hoping that I will then be able to factor out a "square" then reduce the rest to may be a cubic, then apply standard elliptic integration tricks which I have already practiced.  May be I can also then have yet another lattice. A lattice of poles.

Dirty Numerics :: Silly complex games (via well known algebra theorem hehe)  ::: roots
                            $$ 0.64830 + 0.59502i$$
                            $$ 0.64830 - 0.59502i$$
                            $$-0.82428 + 0.53732i$$
                            $$-0.82428 - 0.53732i$$
                            $$-0.32402 + 0.74964i$$
                            $$-0.32402 - 0.74964i$$

Can I even write the above in a symbolic fashion, I CAS(ed) these out after some thinking.

**Edit :**

Consider a lattice with basis $w$ and $w'$ and some transformation between them governed by a $2 \times 2$ matrix. One may use standard techniques to "*accidentally stumble*"(or just follow well-known algorithms for this) on the properties that can be easily found on wikipedia. At any rate. This is a somewhat cool story.

Even cooler is the fact that there is some lattice out there $K$ for a meromorphic function $f(z)$

notwithstanding
$$z_i \sim z_j;$$

$$z_i-z_j \in K$$

The new story I am touching on has a lot of parts. I want to know how one passes from an $f(z)$ to a $K$  You may call the lattice Kevin for simplicity :).

How do Weierstrass functions come into the picture? Would be nice to know

**Version 0.1**

I have an integral in Jacobi form. It is something that can be reduced to an Jacobi elliptic integral of the second kind, or some sum of such beasts. This is somewhat cool. What I want to do is turn this into Weierstrass form. I am considering doing this for a few reasons, one of them is that I want to be able to draw and talk about the associated lattice. Can someone

a) sketch for me the general algorithm for doing the transformation between the forms.  I noticed there is a distinction between Weierstrass form that specifies "periods" and that which specifies "invariants" see for example this link : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html

b) How does the lattice come in?

Think of me as a struggling engineer (really a baby brain) attempting to learn basic math. Is there an extremely simple example of this done somewhere and what would be a good reference for this?

Comment: Please share your integral with us. By the way, it is __Legendre__ elliptic integrals. He wrote the book on elliptic integrals. A complex lattice has many functions associated with it, including "invariants". The latticd is primary.

Comment: @Somos ok, I am going to share it in a few hours. I am just looking over what I have so far.

Comment: @somos  well, the integral is here below. I can give you access to cocal, to see the context in which it arises and some of the tricks I've thrown at it. $$ J = \int dt \sqrt[2]( t^2 (k^2 + t (t (t (((k - 4) k + 3) t + (14 - 4 k) k - 12) + k (6 k - 16) + 9) + (6 - 4 k) k + 2)) - 2)$$

Comment: @Somos please let me know if I can invite you to my cocalc project

Comment: I decided to do reduction, then integration by parts. Then reduce this into some other manageable integrals. I think there is are associated lattices and wierstrass functions.

Comment: Just as a check, if $k=1$ the integrand is $(t-1)\sqrt{2t^3+5t^2+4t+2}.$ Is that correct?

Comment: @Somos  hang on a sec. I am checking something. I think I wrote the euclidean error wrong. Let me go over it, then I will share something. Give me a few hours

Comment: $$x = (k - 2)t^3  + (3-2k) t^2 + kt$$
$$x^2 = k^2 t^6 - 4 k^2 t^5 + 6 k^2 t^4 - 4 k^2 t^3 + k^2 t^2 - 4 k t^6 + 14 k t^5 - 16 k t^4 + 6 k t^3 + 4 t^6 - 12 t^5 + 9 t^4$$
$$y = (1 - t^3)$$
$$y^2 =t^6 -2t^3 +1$$
$$y^2 =(t - 1)^2 (t^2 + t + 1)^2$$

Comment: Euclidean error function
$$ $$
Euclidean Error = $ \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)-1$

$$ \sqrt(((k - 2) t^3 + (3 - 2 k) t^2 + k t)^2 + (1 - t^3)^2) - 1$$
$$ (((k - 2) t^3 + (3 - 2 k) t^2 + k t)^2 + (1 - t^3)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} - 1$$


$$ J =\int dt \sqrt(((k - 2) t^3 + (3 - 2 k) t^2 + k t)^2 + (1 - t^3)^2) - 1$$
$$ J =\int dt  \sqrt(((k - 2) t^3 + (3 - 2 k) t^2 + k t)^2 + (1 - t^3)^2) - \int dt 1 $$

For k = 1;

$$ J_{k=1} = \int dt \sqrt(2 t^6 - 2 t^5 - t^4 + t^2 + 1) - 1 $$

Comment: I want to describe the error by a lattice

Comment: @Somos consider the above

Comment: @somos  I think J can be rearranged so that we can have some special polynomial (vector?) space. containing k's and so forth. Also I want to map the associated elliptic integrals to a lattice.

Comment: I will be working to bring my descriptive language up to par so that communication will be smoother

Comment: hmm slightly different from what I thought it was (I think one can still get a family of J's considering different errors(spaces - -  geometries)) but I think the concept will still work.  I realize there is a series expansion for this special case too, but I want to see that lattice

Comment: Well ping me . Also cocalc invite is still open too :D

Comment: Look at my profile for my home page.

Comment: ok, I just sent you an invite. Once you get in , the path to file is The  path to the file is Project X > Bezier Curves > Polished_v1 > Mildly_coherent_a1_2018-03-21-013356     . The content is somewhat organized though, I will however make it easier to navigate. please look over and make edits as desired. We can explore and calculate on there, and discuss there and here on progress

Comment: @somos, I exploited the fundamental theorem of algebra to locate and plot roots.  I want to be able to factor over a field extension. I am curious as to how to know the proper extension. I am also kind of want to know how to get sage to give me the symbolic versions of this stuff

Comment: @Somos In polished, I have 2 new files, and have made minute edits

Comment: @Somos, so I understand the concept of splitting fields, and so forth. I have not quite understood how to get the appropriate field extension Q(something, something etc) and how to factor this.. (2t6−2t5−t4+t2+1) except over $C$

Comment: I have checked the eisenstein criterion. At any rate, I have factored over   $C$ and something else for a test, as you will for example find in one of the other files in the mentioned folder

Comment: I think once I have done the appropriate factoring, I can the set up the integrals and plot a the poles for them if I am in C, or perhaps , something else If I am in some other field

Comment: I guess so far I'm just doing some trivial ground work hehe

Comment: Actually the field extension thing is a bit far fetched for several reasons

Comment: I am hoping to capture multiplicity of 2 somewhere so that I have some stuff slipping out of the root.

Comment: then If I have a cubic or even quartic, I'd know how to beat it up